# Mac OSX Dev : Custom ViewController not receiving Mouse Events

Tags: macos, events, mouse, nsresponder

I need to create a quick demo app (asap). It has a NSImageView (with a full window sized photo) and the mouse point clicks, drags and moves over this.

There is also an NSTextField (Label) to show the mouse event and position over the window.

I've created a project using the Cocoa app template, and create a new ViewController, added that view controllers view to the windows contextView, and the NSImageView shows up fine - as does the label.

However events such as

```
- ( void ) mouseDown:( NSEvent * )event;
- ( void ) mouseMoved:( NSEvent * )event;
```

Don't do anything. If I have an NSLog in there, they never get hit.

I have set:

```
- ( BOOL ) becomesFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
```

but that also doesn't make any difference.

Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong? I'm an iOS Dev of 2+ years and this is my first Mac OS X app. I have to get this working in the next 24hours :(

Comment: where are you defining your "`mouseDown:`" method? Also, since this has nothing to do with iOS (aside from you being an iOS Dev of 2+ years), I'm removing the iOS tag.

Comment: The mouse events were trying to be used in the 'View Controller' class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mouse events were trying to be used in the 'View Controller' class.

I've since found a sample code (3rd party) that shows they have to be in the 'NSView' object, so I've had to create a custom NSView object programatically to track the mouse and it's all working.

Here's the URL:

http://www.markdouma.com/developer/MouseMovedvsTrackingAreas.zip

Answer (score 1):

To catch mouse down/up events, you should subclass `NSImageView` and define `mouseDown:`/`mouseUp:` there. Then you can forward these events to controller.